# How to stop converting ^^M into space?

Tags: token-lists

Is it possible to make `^^M` visible in the list of tokens? Now it just gets converted to space, but I need it to be visible in tokens. This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iexec}
\usepackage{environ}
\newtoks\tempnotetoks
\NewEnviron{note}{%
  \catcode`\\=12%
  \tempnotetoks=\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \iexec{echo '\the\tempnotetoks'}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{note}
One \foo
  Two
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

This is what the log says:

```
iexec: [echo 'One \foo Two' > iexec.tmp]
```

However, I want something like this:

```
iexec: [echo 'One \space \foo \eol \space \space Two' > iexec.tmp]
```

I would like both end-of-line and spaces to become tokens.

Comment: Isn't this behavior typical for `verbatim` environments? Maybe go the other way around: use a `verbatim` environment and re-enable the use of `\foo` (and maybe change the font)

Comment: I need my own environment to behave similar to verbatim

Comment: `\obeylines\obeyspaces`

Comment: @yegor256 Yes, I just thought that it might be easier to tweak an already existing environment that provides most of what you need instead of creating a new one from scratch.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you please post a complete example? I will gladly accept it.

Comment: The code I put in a comment answers the question in the title but the code in the code example uses NewEviron so the body is already parsed in a macro definitio so catcode changes do nothing. (Also I would not run code from the internet that does `! Package iexec Error: You must run latex with --shell-escape option`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass through a token register to suppress expansion with e-tex, you can use `\unexpanded` also no need for a package to grab an environment body with current latex.

Because you are grabbing the body catcode changes within the definition have no effect, but you can change catcodes in the hook before the body is grabbed.

I use `\show` here rather than shell escape,

Newlines are converted to an active cntrl-M which is `\let` to `\obeyedline` I show here how to define that although it shows as an unexpanded control M here as expansion is suppressed (it is a single ascii 13 character, it just shows as `^^M` in the log output)

```
\documentclass{article}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{note}{b}{%
  \edef\qqq{echo '\unexpanded{#1}'}%
  \show\qqq
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{note}
One \foo
  Two
\end{note}

\AddToHook{env/note/before}{\def\obeyedline{[newline]}\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\begin{note}
One \foo
  Two
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
> \qqq=macro:
->echo 'One \foo Two'.
\environment note code ...panded {#1}'}\show \qqq 
                                                  
l.12 \end
         {note}
? 
> \qqq=macro:
->echo '^^MOne \foo ^^M  Two^^M'.
\environment note code ...panded {#1}'}\show \qqq 
                                                  
l.18 \end
         {note}
?
```

where the effect of `\obeylines\obeyspaces` is seen in the second call.

---

---

For  more complete "verbatim write" look at the code for the `filecontents` environment but a simple version is

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\nfile
\immediate\openout\nfile=\jobname.txt

\NewDocumentEnvironment{note}{b}{%
  \immediate\write\nfile{\detokenize{#1}}%
}{}

\AddToHook{env/note/before}{%
\newlinechar=\endlinechar
\obeylines\obeyspaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{note}
One \foo
  Two
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

which makes a `.txt` file with

```
One \foo 
  Two
```

Comment: If I replace `\qqq` with `\iexec`, the file it creates DOESN'T contain tokens, but only "expanded" text. However, I want tokens to be saved to the file... Can you adjust your example please?

Comment: @yegor256 as I say I am not going to use iexec. Can you be clearer about what you did and what you expected. Here you should get a `^^M` token (which is a non-space token as requested) or the expansion of that, `[newline]` depending whether or not you suppress expansion with `\unexpanded` (or `\newtoks`) . Perhaps add a second example to your question showing the output you got.

Comment: can you make your `note` environment save `#1` to some file? Then, make sure there are `^^M` in that file.

Comment: BTW, you don't use any packages that require `--shell-escape`, like `minted` for example? :)

Comment: I know the code of minted, but even then I am very cautious about running it on a document I did not write. I do not know iexec at all and am not prepared to give it full access to every file I have on this machine without doing a full code review first. @yegor256

Comment: @yegor256 see update